# Regex for postcode with - allowed

Tags: java, regex

This is my regex for postcodes

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,9}$
```

but `A-12345` is not allowed. How to change the regex that `-` will be also allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `-` at the beginning or at the end of the character set (`[...]`):

```
^[-a-zA-Z0-9]{1,9}$
```

*Why at the beginning or at the end?*:  If `-` is placed as the first or the last character, it will match `-` literally instead of matching range of characters.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,9}$
```

This will match strings consisting of 1 to 9 Latin letters, decimal digits or hyphens. If you use the [CASE_INSENSITIVE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE) flag, you can simplify this to:

```
^[a-z0-9-]{1,9}$
```